# Javascript: `new a()` vs `a()` - new operator vs functioncall()

Tags: javascript, object, properties, console, new-operator

```
function a() {
    this.a = function () {
        console.log("In A");
    }
    this.b = function () {
        console.log("In B");
    }
    this.c = function (cb) {
        console.log("In C ");
    }
    this.d = function (cb) {
        cb();
        console.log("In D");
    }

    this.d(function () {
        this.a();
        this.b();
        this.c();
    });
}
```

1. `var A = a();`

IN A
IN B
IN C
IN D

2. `var A = new a();`

IN A
IN B
IN C
IN D
IN B
IN C
IN D

Could anyone explain me how this works?

Also, any suggestions on links where I can find such interesting problems/questions?

Thanks, in advance :)

Comment: This is a horrible example of a constructor call. If you are wanting to learn about them, find a different source.

Comment: Your callback in `d` runs in the global scope and invokes the global `a`, not `this.a`.